# Return value of smart contract function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

In a truffle project, I have a smart contract function as below:

```
function add_something(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName) external returns (address) {
    // Do some updates etc 
    return someAddress;
}
```

After the smart contract is deployed using `truffle migrate` command, I want to run a JS script to call some functions on the deployed smart contract. (`truffle exec add.js`)

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");
module.exports = async function(callback) {

    let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    let instance = await MyContract.deployed();

    let result = await instance.add_something("Stack", "Overflow", {from: accounts[0]});
    console.log(result);
```

**Expected**: I want to have the return value (address) in the result.

**Actual**: **result** contains the following Transaction receipt object:

```
{"tx":"0x2e5b2fb1a9dd023be04e12f73fcea3cab84214258be71ac2f76b86c58e485433","receipt":{"transactionHash":"0x2e5b2fb1a9dd023be04e12f73fcea3cab84214258be71ac2f76b86c58e485433","transactionIndex":0,"blockHash":"0xbdbef8e9b38cd66748eca51809869185deb61d00bb0f93916f76ee5594ca945d","blockNumber":45,"from":"0x75c1df3c54b6eb371169737fb62f2c5b7c178479","to":"0x786676da2567c51c83b56888e48030fa5fea0e03","gasUsed":2406988,"cumulativeGasUsed":2406988,"contractAddress":null,"logs":[],"status":true,"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","rawLogs":[]},"logs":[]}
```

I have tried using .methods, call() and send(), but get the following errors:

```
let result = await instance.add_something("Stack", "Overflow", {from: accounts[0]}).call();
TypeError: instance.add_something(...).call is not a function
```

Please suggest a suitable solution to read the return value of a non-view smart contract function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you should consider using events. Under normal circumstances solidity functions do not return a value to begin with but events can change that

```
contract Test {
   event someEvent(string _someString);
   function doSomething()public external {      
      emit someEvent("This is some event");
   }
}
```

> You can also pass a variable like this

```
function doSomething(string _somethingGoesHere)public external {      
      emit someEvent(_somethingGoesHere);
 }
```

You can then go onto the JavaScript code and read the result or rather the output like so

```
var abi = /* abi as generated using compiler */;
var Test = web3.eth.contract(abi);
/* Deploy your contract and save the address*/
var testContract = Test.at("0x1234...ab67" /* address */);

var event = testContract.doSomething(function(error, result) {
   if (!error)console.log(result);
});
```

This was you do not need to use any return value or a view function, instead you just read whatever is returned or rather emitted from the Solidity event

Comment: How do I pass my parameters to `testContract.doSomething` function? It is giving Error: Invalid number of parameters. 

Also, can you shed some info on what is the better approach - return value or emit event?

Comment: After deploying your contract you can just do something like
`let result = await testContract.doSomething("Doing Something")`
  `print(result.receipt.rawData)`

When it comes to which is better I think it all depends on the use case. Events are better when you just want to log and display information, I believe the return is better when you will use that function's value later on for example in another function

Comment: Thanks, but from the logs I pasted, it is clear that result.receipt does not contain *rawData*. It is just printing `undefined`

Comment: No the logs you posted are using a return value which does not contain anything like that. Have you tried doing it after you compiled the contract with the events?
In your case rawData is empty because there is no event to emit something from that function, if you did this say in Remix using a VM you would have the return value without emitting an event but this is not the case with real deployment

Comment: I got how to read data emitted through event:

`result.logs[0].args[0]`

Though I am still not clear how to read the *return value* of smart contract function call. Not finding it in documentation [here](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#processing-transaction-results) as well.

Comment: Not sure about the documentation but the way it usually works is by declaring a variable as the return value of the smart contract deployment. I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Thank you, but it still didn't solve the problem of reading back the return value of smart contract function call in my JS file. I am working with events for now.